# How to disable the standard css in Spring MVC

Tags: css, spring-mvc, spring-roo

I'm trying to build a web application in Spring using spring roo and I want to use a new style sheet as opposed to the standard css file that it automatically uses.  I've been able to link the new style sheet in my jsp with no problem, but when I use the developer tools in google chrome and go to the network tab the standard style sheet is still there and is changing some elements on my page, even though I don't link it in my jsp.  There's something built in causing it to load automatically and I can't find out how to disable it.  I've spent a lot of time looking at the webmvc-config.xml file and and the theme.tagx file and I'm really not sure how to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look at file `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/util/load-scripts.tagx` this tag is used to include any css/js assets on html headers. This done by *Tiles* library.

If you want to configure global visualization layout review this files:

- `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml`: *Tiles* layouts definition
- `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/layouts/*.jspx`: *Tiles* layouts templates
- `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/*.jspx`: Common templates for layouts (menu, header)
- `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/util/load-scripts.tagx`: Default tag to include css/js assets

To read more about Tiles you can read [project documentation](https://tiles.apache.org/2.2/framework/index.html)

Good luck!